# Random Selections from Arrays

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, random

I am creating a game in Unity. I'm in the planning stage of it right now, but I'm trying to work out a problem I've come to. The game involves randomly selected objects from three different categories falling and the player has to catch the particular objects in particular bins.

So here's what needs to happen:
One or two of the arrays must be randomly chosen, one or two of the objects within that particular array must be chosen, no more than four objects can fall at once, the different objects must fall from different places and fall at different times.

Now I have a clip of code that I got from another project I did that's written in JavaScript (which is what I've been using, but I could also do it in Boo or C++) that solves part of the last point. It chooses a random location along the x access and then has the object fall until y=0, and then it resets.

```
function Update()
{
 transform.position.y -= 50 * Time.deltaTime;
 if(transform.position.y < 0)
 {
 transform.position.y = 50;
 transform.position.x = Random.Range(0,60);
 transform.position.z = -16;
 }
}
```

I'm going to rewrite part of it to say that it will reset after it hits a particular collider, yields for a short time period, and find then a new random and drop that instead. But what I'm having problems with is the actual randomizing of the objects. I have six objects in each of the three arrays, and I've looked for codes where something is chosen from an array by numerical value, but nothing about randomly choosing one of the arrays and then choosing something within the random array. Neither have I found anything about the random selection in JavaScript, Boo, or C++.

Any information on this code would be helpful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To select one object at random from one of three arrays at random, you better work with an array of array. You then will need to generate two random numbers and store them as indexes to the array of arrays.

so instead of three different arrays, initialize a single array

```
var a = [];
a.push([1,2,3]);
a.push([10,20]);
a.push([100,200,300,400]);
```

and then

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length);
var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*a[i].length);
var o = a[i][j];
```